# Exercício com While ou Do While utilizando variável CHAR

Tags: c

Boa noite gente! e o seguinte.. eu preciso fazer esse exercicio aqui usando while em C:

> e) Em uma eleição presidencial existem 2 candidatos. Os votos são informados atráves de códigos. Para o candidato 1 o código é A para o candidado 2 o código é B. O algoritmo só pode receber o código A ou B, qualquer outro caracter digitado deve ser ignorado e uma mensagem de código inválido deve ser emitida. Elabore um algoritmo que calcule e escreva ao final o número total de votos do candidato A e o número total de votos do candidato B. O finalização do algoritmo se dará quando o usuário digitar código F.

Praticamente todos os exercicios que fiz ate agora ou foi com float ou com int, ou seja, nao sei direito como usar char, ate onde eu sei ele armazena um simbolo so, e precisa colocar ele entre ' ', mas eu nao sei como escrever esse codigo, provavelmente o que eu escrevi esteja errado, alguem consegue dar alguma dica? eu fiz uma anotacao ali no codigo, se poderem dar uma olhada no //

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char escolha;
int valorA=0, valorB=0;

main()
{
    do{
        printf("Digite A para candidato 1, ou B para candidato 2 (F para terminar): ");
        scanf(" %c", escolha);

        if((escolha!='A')||(escolha!='B')||(escolha!='F')){
            printf("Codigo invalido\n");
        }else if(escolha == 'A'){
            valorA = valorA + 1;
        }else if(escolha == 'B'){
            valorB = valorB + 1;
        }

    }while(escolha == 'F'); //talvez oq esta em cima nao esteja TOTALMENTE errado, mas eu acho que o maior erro ta aqui no while, 
                            //eu quero encerrar o loop escrevendo F..  

    printf("A quantidade de Pessoas que votaram no candidato 1 foi: %i e do candidato 2: %i", valorA, valorB);
```

Comment: Aqui: `scanf(" %c", escolha);` você tem que informar o endereço: `scanf(" %c", &escolha);`. Talvez seu `if` deva ser: `if((escolha!='A') && (escolha!='B') && (escolha!='F')){` (para ser considerado inválido quando diferentes destes 3) e no `do ... while` a condição deva ser: `(escolha != 'F');` (para permanecer no loop até que seja informado 'F').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O tipo char é um tipo integral assim como o int, ele pode conter um valor entre -127 a 128 se assinado ou 0 a 255 sem sinal. Porém, ele é mais usado para guardar um caractere que no final das contas vai ser um valor numérico.

No seu while você compara se a escolha é igual a F, quando você tem que comparar se a escolha é diferente de F para que o loop continue acontecendo.

Se você pretende apenas adicionar mais 1 a uma variável de cada vez, você pode incrementá-la com o operador ++.

Aqui uma implementação:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int valorA = 0;
  int valorB = 0;

  char escolha = 0;

  do {
    printf("Digite A para candidato 1, ou B para candidato 2 (F para terminar): ");
    scanf(" %c", &escolha);

    if(escolha == 'A') {
      ++valorA;
    }else if(escolha == 'B') {
      ++valorB;
    }else if(escolha != 'F') {
      printf("Código inválido!\n");
    }
  }while(escolha != 'F');

  printf("Votos para o candidato 1: %d\n", valorA);
  printf("Votos para o candidato 2: %d\n", valorB);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah, entendi! eu nao estava conseguindo sacar a logica com char, nao sei, pra mim quando e uma variavel com numeros fica mt mais facil, ate pq comecei a pouco tempo a programar, deve ser por isso haha, valeu cara!

Answer (score 1):

Como no enunciado no exercício não há contraindicação de usar a estrutura [switch-case](http://linguagemc.com.br/o-comando-switch-case-em-c/), tomei a liberdade de melhorar seu código, acredito que com esta estrutura ele ficará mais legível.

Faça o seguinte:

```
do{
        printf("Digite A para candidato 1, ou B para candidato 2 (F para terminar): ");
        scanf(" %c", &escolha);

        switch (escolha){
        case 'A':
        valorA = valorA + 1;
        break;

        case 'B':
        valorB = valorB + 1;
        break;

        case 'F':
        break;

        default:
        printf("Codigo invalido\n");
        }
    }while(escolha != 'F');
```

Há melhorias para fazer no seu código, entretanto deixo que você as faça. Uma melhoria seria converter a entrada para maiusculo, evitando possíveis problemas futuros.

Recomendo a leitura:[toupper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper)

Comment: Valeuu pela dica! eu pensei no inicio em usar o switch, mas eu achava que so era possivel usar ele com numeros.. tipo case 1, case 2.. etc. foi bom saber isso, obrigado.